# Howler audio does not play on AR site after switching active tab

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, howler.js, 8thwall-xr

I'm working on an 8th Wall AR website (https://ar.physiciansweekly.com/?experience=Psor-23-Jul) which was working fine until recently.

If you load the page in Safari on an iPhone, then switch away to another tab/window, then come back to the website, the audio that should play (via howler.js) when you tap the "Start" button does not play. No audio plays.

I have no idea if this is a Howler thing, or a Safari thing (which updated recently to 16.5.1), or how to diagnose.